# Error in Returning Value of Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Expected output: "x is 2" 
Actual output: "x is undefined"

app.js

```
var x = db_Save(req.session.user);
console.log('x is ' + x);
```

dbFile.js

```
var db_Save= function (user) {

    // return 2; /* 'x is 2' would print;

    console.log('function returns "undefined" before following');
    userProfile.find({Email: profileInstance.Email}, function(err, doc){
        console.log('prints after "x is undefined"');
        return 2; // does not get returned  
    });
}
```

Comment: You're passing an anonymous function as a callback to another function - where exactly do you expect its return value to go to?

Comment: See [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call). Even though you're probably not doing ajax in there, the problem and its solutions are the same.

Comment: Node.js asynchronous, and you need to understand concept of being event-driven, rather than functional in the way execution is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a callback function :

```
db_Save(req.session.user,function(x){
    console.log('x is ' + x);
});

var db_Save= function (user,callback) {
    userProfile.find({Email: profileInstance.Email}, function(err, doc){                                
        callback(2);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

userProfile.find is asynchronous which means it gets kicked off but does not return 2 until after your console.log has fired. Your callback is this function:

```
 function(err, doc){                              
    console.log('prints after "x is undefined"');
    return 2; // does not get returned  
  }
```

You give this as the second argument of your call to `userProfile.find`. When the find is completed, the function is called returning 2, but by this time it is too late and you have already console.logged x which was undefined at the time.